# How to replace the value in a list with their ordinal number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, replace

I have a list:

```
a = [[6, 8, 12, 15], [2, 5, 13], [1], [5], [6, 15]]
```

And I want to replace all of the value in the inner lists to their ordinal values like:

```
b = [[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2], [3], [4, 4]]
```

I tried this:

```
for jj in a:
    for uu in range(0, len(jj)):
        for k,q in enumerate(a):
            jj[uu] == k
```

It didn't output the list I wanted. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

Is this your desired output?

```
In [1]: a = [[6, 8, 12, 15], [2, 5, 13], [1], [5], [6, 15]]

In [2]: b = [[idx] * len(sublist) for idx, sublist in enumerate(a)]

In [3]: b
Out[3]: [[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2], [3], [4, 4]]
```

This answer is also more Pythonic than versions using `range(len(a))`.

Answer (score 2):

May be this can help.

```
[[i]*len(a[i]) for i in range(len(a))]
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2], [3], [4, 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The others answers are good, here's another list comprehension that also works:

```
>>> a = [[6, 8, 12, 15], [2, 5, 13], [1], [5], [6, 15]]
>>> b = [[i for _ in y] for i, y in enumerate(a)]
>>> b
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2], [3], [4, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's use List comprehensions to solve this -

```
a = [[6, 8, 12, 15], [2, 5, 13], [1], [5], [6, 15]]
b = [[i for j in range(len(a[i]))] for i in range(len(a))]
b
    [[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2], [3], [4, 4]]
```